# NestJS from JSON request payload to object of a specific type

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am working on a backend api in NestJS, and at somepoint I need to compare the objects i receive through a POST controller with something from the database.

My issue is that when i try to call the method `incomeDto.equalsIncomeEntity(income);`, i can't because the `incomeDto` is of type `Object` instead of type `CreateIncomeDto`.

And i don't know how to make NestJS or TypeScript transform the list of `Object`in a list of `CreateIncomeDto`.

I want something more optimum than creating in the `CreateIncomeDto` and use that to instantiate my objects. Something that is turning as soon as they are in Controller in the objects that the Controller is expecting.

One way i've found to do it, is to create a static `initDto()` method in the `CreateIncomeDto` and use this method to initialize my object. But it doesn't seem quite natural.

The tech stack is NestJS with TypeScript and as ORM i use TypeORM

Thank you for your help.

Below is the code:

This is in the controller

```
    @Post('list')
    @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
    public async saveIncomeList( @Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true})) incomeDtoList: CreateIncomeDto[], @User('userId') userId: number) {
        return await this.incomeService.saveIncomeList(incomeDtoList, userId);
    }
```

this is the CreateIncomeDto class with the method that I need to use for comparison.
The logic in the method is not yet finished, but it's not the cause of the problem

```
export class CreateIncomeDto {

    @IsNumber()
    id: number;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNumber()
    currentAmount: number;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNumber()
    goalAmount: number;

    @IsNumber()
    yearlyAmount: number;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    recurrence: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    type: string;


    public equalsIncomeEntity(incomeToCompare: Income): boolean{
        return JSON.stringify(incomeToCompare) === JSON.stringify(this);
    }

    public static initDto(incomeDto: CreateIncomeDto): CreateIncomeDto {
        const { currentAmount, goalAmount, recurrence, type, id } = incomeDto;
        const income = new CreateIncomeDto();
        income.id = id.toString() === "" ? null : id;
        income.currentAmount = currentAmount;
        income.goalAmount = goalAmount;
        income.type = type;
        income.recurrence = Recurrence[recurrence];
        return income;
    }
}
```

and this is in the service where i iterate over the list i receive from frontend and compare with a copy from the database if the object has the 'id' property

```
    public async saveIncomeList(incomeDtoList: CreateIncomeDto[], userId): Promise<void> {
        try {
            for (let incomeDto of incomeDtoList) {
                if (incomeDto.id.toString() != "") {
                    const incomeFromDb = await this.incomeRepository.findOne(incomeDto.id);
                    incomeDto = CreateIncomeDto.initDto(incomeDto)
                    if (incomeDto.equalsIncomeEntity(incomeFromDb)) {
                        console.log("THEY ARE EQUAL")
                    }

                } else {
                    await this.create(incomeDto, userId)
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            throw new HttpException(err, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

the payload sent from the frontend is this

```
[
{"type":"tses 1","recurrence":"WEEKLY","currentAmount":23213,"goalAmount":12312,"yearlyAmount":null,"id":1},
{"type":"Test 2","recurrence":"WEEKLY","currentAmount":23213,"goalAmount":12312,"yearlyAmount":null,"id":2}
]
```

Comment: as a note this is not correct, `JSON.stringify(incomeToCompare) === JSON.stringify(this)` if the order of fileds are changed it will return false, ex `JSON.stringify({a:1, b2}) === JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1})` returns false, while they are same, use deppEqual lib instead

Comment: use https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#plaintoclass instead of manual object creation

Comment: Thank you @Reza, do you have some other suggestions how i can compare them in an optimal way. Something else than comparing field by field

Comment: Thank you @MarcStroebel, i'll look into that

Comment: @robertsci use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal